# How can I avoid app names in inapp item titles returned from Google Play getSkuDetails?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'd like the use the `getSkuDetails()` call from the In-app Billing v3 API to dynamically display a list of inapp purchase options with properly translated titles and relevant price.

However, the "title" property from getSkuDetails() seems to always be of the form `"<item title> (app name)"`, which is less than useful. How can I get only the item title itself without the app name without hacking the string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is the way it is. I mean even I didn't like it, obviously user knows that he is buying from the app but I think Google is going to reply it in this way only

Comment: I have the same situation, and based on this, I'm going to run that string through a filter and strip out anything in parenthesis before showing it to the user.  It just seems like a kludge.

Comment: Also having the same issue. Still no solution for that issue?

Comment: the solution is: replace('(PROJECT_ID)", "") - google what are you doing? srsly? Makes no sense

Comment: Actually this is very  awkward. If you look the json you can see a property called name that you cannot access by getter. We can remove the app name easily so why don't just give us access to it.

Answer (score 13):

As no one has replied with an actual regex pattern to match the app name in parentheses in the SKU title I thought I just post the code here for further reference:

```
// matches the last text surrounded by parentheses at the end of the SKU title
val skuTitleAppNameRegex = """(?> \(.+?\))$""".toRegex()

val titleWithoutAppName = skuDetails.title.replace(skuTitleAppNameRegex, "")
```

The regex is as strict as possible to allow for additional text in parentheses **within** your SKU title without removing it as well (e.g. SKU titles like *Premium (Subscription)* would stay as they are). The only thing you should avoid is parentheses in your app name, but with a little tweaking of the regex you could work around that as well.

As regexes are notoriously expensive to build it is advisable to store it in a field and avoid constructing them each time over when you are parsing your SKUs.

Answer (score 4):

Adapting [@ubuntudroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304266/ubuntudroid) answer to Java, I made it work like this:

```
String skuTitleAppNameRegex = "(?> \\(.+?\\))$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(skuTitleAppNameRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(skuDetails.getTitle());
String titleWithoutAppName = m.replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String productTitleWithAppName=skuDetails.getTitle();

String productTitleWithoutAppName = productTitleWithAppName.substring(0, productTitleWithAppName.indexOf("("));
```

Comment: OP was looking for a way to get the title without the string hack.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for this. The following should work. This is in C# but you can guess how you can do it in Java or any other language.

```
string title = getTitle(); // get title
int appNameStartIndex = title.LastIndexOf("("); // find last index of (.
string titleWithoutAppName = title.Substring(0, appNameStartIndex); // and :)
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the name of the SKU without the app name in parantheses is transfered with the SKU, but there is no getter to retrieve it.

If you have a deeper look into the implementation of `SkuDetails` class, then you see, that this whole thing is based on a json String (also debugging gives you this json).
And this json string contains not only the title with the apps name, but also a name field with the SKUs name only.

The SKUs json representation can be retrieved with `SkuDetails.getOriginalJson()`.

So if it better fits your needs, then you can of course retrieve the SKU name directly from the data, returned from Google.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in development builds, I'd get a value like `My product (com.test.myapp (unreviewed))`. Here's a version of the regex that handles the nested parentheses and keeps other parentheses in your product name intact:

```
const removeAppNameFromProductTitle = (title: string) => {
  const regex = /( \([^()]*\)$)|( \([^)]*\)\)$)/im;
  return title.replace(regex, '');
};
```

The code is in TypeScript (React Native), but I'm sure you can adapt. Here's a gist with test cases: https://gist.github.com/thmsobrmlr/732ecf958f600ec38e89c4e8ff57f3dd.